# Issue with imports from one file to another - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, import

I have a destination.dart file including lists of buildings' details, and have imported the file into the building_screen.dart and building_carousel.dart. However, although it used to be error free, now i get error that Destination needs to be defined as class, despite its existence in destination.dart and the import. How can I solve this issue?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; (this is where it shows error)

class Building {
  String imageUrl;
  String name;
  String description;
  String date;
  String details;
  List<String> imagePaths;

  Building({
    this.imageUrl,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.date,
    this.details,
    this.imagePaths,
  });
}


List<Building> buildings = [
  Building(
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/close-up_library.jpg',
    name: 'The Library',
    description: 'View the innovative Library of Birmingham',
    date: 'Date built: 2010',
    details: ' '
    ];
```

the other files are importing this file to display the buildings.
Also when I try to run the app, a "Null check operator used on a null value" error is shown and the "Dart compiler exited unexpectedly".

Comment: Can you provide the code of your files and how you import them? It looks like you haven't defined a class in there, since the error tells exactly that?

Comment: yes I have added the code to the question now